# How to build executable micronaut jar

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, micronaut

I've created a micronaut application using

```
mn create-app my-app
```

It generated the project structure with a Dockerfile. The docker file is looking for the file `my-app-*-all.jar` to copy.

```
FROM openjdk:14-alpine
COPY build/libs/my-app-*-all.jar my-app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote", "-Xmx128m", "-jar", "my-app.jar"]
```

How do I generate the my-app-*-all.jar?

`./gradlew jar` is not generating the (-all) jar.

**EDITED:** It's only generating `my-app-0.1.jar`, and when I use that jar, it is giving an error.
`no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/my-app-0.1.jar`
Do I need to add any additional lines in build.gradle file?

Comment: With the template provided by the CLI, `./gradlew assemble` should build the jar, the task from the shadowJar will build the `*-all.jar`. Do you have any errors when running `./gradlew assemble` ? (especially because of the `new` reserved keyword from your project name ?

Comment: @Airy I am not getting any errors `./gradlew jar` and `./gradlew assemble` are both generating the jar. But when I use the jar file in Dockerfile or in local. I'm getting the error `no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/my-app-0.1.jar`

Comment: Found that someone already asked a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755410/how-to-create-micronauts-fat-jar-without-shadow-plugin

Comment: "Do I need to add any additional lines in build.gradle file?" - That is impossible to say without knowing what is currently in your `build.gradle`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown `build.gradle` is auto generated by micronaut-cli. I believe, the generated file will be the same for anyone who runs `mn create-app my-app`. I'm good for now, since `./gradlew shadowJar` did the magic.

Comment: Which version of Micronaut are you using?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I generate the my-app-*-all.jar?

If you are using the default Gradle build config, `assemble` will do it.

```
~ $ mn --version
Micronaut Version: 2.0.0
JVM Version: 1.8.0_252
~ $ 
~ $ mn create-app my-app
| Application created at /Users/jeffscottbrown/my-app
~ $ 
~ $ cd my-app
my-app $ 
my-app $ ./gradlew assemble

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
10 actionable tasks: 10 executed
my-app $ 
my-app $ ls -l build/libs 
total 27160
-rw-r--r--  1 jeffscottbrown  staff  13473553 Jul 16 10:23 my-app-0.1-all.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 jeffscottbrown  staff      1457 Jul 16 10:23 my-app-0.1.jar
```

Comment: NOTE: `./gradlew assemble` will not generate the `*all.jar` when you use jib feature while generating the project. i.e. when you use `mn create-app my-app --features jib`

Answer (score -1):

```
./gradlew shadowJar
```

will generate the `my-app-0.1-all.jar`.

NOTE: At the time of providing this answer, the shadow plugin seems to be missing when I use jib feature while generating the project.
i.e. when you use
`mn create-app my-app --features jib`
shadowPlugin is not present in `build.gradle` file.
If that is the case: Add the following lines in build.gradle

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "6.0.0"
}

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

Comment: "when you use mn create-app my-app --features jib shadowPlugin is not present in build.gradle" - That is a different scenario than was asked in the original question.  The original question specifically says `mn create-app my-app`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Sorry if it is confusing. The answer was for the original question only. I am just stating a fact and I want future readers to be aware. `mn create-app my-app` has the shadow plugin in build.gradle and the command `mn create-app my-app --features jib` doesn't have the shadow plugin in build.gradle. I'll try to edit the answer and make it as a note.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.  All the best!